# Wordpress taxanomy error

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: job list
Plugin URI: http://example.com/
Description: A complete and practical example of use of the Settings API. This plugin creates a new plugin administration page.
Author: WROX
Author URI: http://wrox.com
*/
function dwwp_register_taxonomy() {
    $singular = 'Location';
    $plural = 'Locations';
    $slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => $plural,
        'singular_name'              => $singular,
        'search_items'               => 'Search ' . $plural,
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular ' . $plural,
        'all_items'                  => 'All ' . $plural,
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit ' . $singular,
        'update_item'                => 'Update ' . $singular,
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New ' . $singular,
        'new_item_name'              => 'New ' . $singular . ' Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural . ' with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove ' . $plural,
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used ' . $plural,
        'not_found'                  => 'No ' . $plural . ' found.',
        'menu_name'                  => $plural,
    );
    $args = array(
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $$slug ),
        );
    register_taxonomy( 'location', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'dwwp_register_taxonomy' );
```

I creating wordpress plugin and i dont know taxonomy well it is giving me error 
as follows..
Notice: Undefined variable: location in
 C:\XAMMP2\htdocs\rateIt\wp-content\plugins\job-listing.php on line 37
 (this is line 37= register_taxonomy( 'location', $args );)
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\XAMMP2\htdocs\rateIt\wp-includes\class-wp-taxonomy.php on line 360

Comment: If Given above is your Code You Have an error in 35th line ie `'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => $$slug ),` . Here `$slug` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the object_type argument (Name of the object type for the `taxonomy` object. Object-types can be built-in Post Type or any `Custom Post Type` that may be registered) so you need to use it like:

```
register_taxonomy( 'location', array('post type / custom post type') $args );
```

as well as an extra `$` symbol on the `$slug`.

please have a look of this reference here.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy